# SharePoint Web Part to View List from Different SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working on SharePoint 2010 instance. I want to be able to view list content in the SharePoint site that this list doesn't belong to. My site does not even share the same site collection as the one containing the list. Is this possible without the custom SharePoint solution coding? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround:

http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Cross-Site-List-Snapshot.aspx

This will work across site collections, as long as the source and target pages are in the same domain. It'll work fine if your only purpose is to display the content, not use the context menus.

Other solutions like Data View Web Part or Content Query Web Part won't work across site collections.